# Entity Framework taking a long time to return when I use Include

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make a simple query in my database with EF 6, C# and .NET 6. I have a table of users and a table of departments, the relationship between them is many to many but even though there are only 7 departments, 2 users and only one relationship, the query is taking a long time - more than 2 seconds! How can I improve it?

Here is the method that makes the query

```
public async Task<List<User>> FindAllAsync()
{
    try
    {
        return await _context.Users
                             .Include(obj => obj.Departments)
                             .ToListAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

In my `User` class I have an `ICollection` of `Departments` and vice-versa

```
public ICollection<Department>? Departments { get; set; }
```

I try to make the method synchronous but the result was the same and if I remove the inc the query ends very quickly.

Comment: can you share your table schema? and what if you run the expected query directly into the database?

Comment: The relationships are likely to be improperly defined, the other thing you can do is capture the SQL that is generated and that might shed some light, but it is definitely something strange in the schema

Comment: What *exactly* takes 2s? Does that include application startup etc? What does it say when you log the query? That said, it's always extremely hard to answer performance questions.

Comment: Please include the full class definition for Department. One thing that does come to mind is if Lazy Loading is enabled and Department contains several `virtual` references/collections. This would cause the serializer to "touch" a lot of tables with individual queries when the Department is included. (Since User.Departments is not `virtual` that doesn't trigger lazy loads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming SQL Server?

This has to be something with your SQL Server schema. I would run the query directly in SSMS and hit <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd> to display the Actual Execution Plan.

Click the Execution Plan tab inside SSMS and look for where it goes sideways.